# How to implement the Unit Test for DatasourceConfiguration with HikariConfig

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, hikaricp

Here is my `DatasourceConfiguration.java` file. It's a configuration file, to set up the Hikari config and the QuartzDatasource is built based on the Hikari config.

```
import com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig;
import com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.quartz.QuartzDataSource;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class DatasourceConfiguration {
  @Value("${spring.datasource.scheduler.jdbcUrl}")
  private String jdbcUrl;

  @Value("${spring.datasource.scheduler.username}")
  private String userName;

  @Value("${spring.datasource.scheduler.driverClassname}")
  private String driverClassname;

  @Value("${spring.datasource.scheduler.password}")
  private String password;

  @Bean
  public HikariConfig hikariConfig() {
    HikariConfig hikariConfig = new HikariConfig();
    hikariConfig.setDriverClassName(driverClassname);
    hikariConfig.setJdbcUrl(jdbcUrl);
    hikariConfig.setUsername(userName);
    hikariConfig.setPassword(password);
    return hikariConfig;
  }

  @Bean(name = "quartzDataSource")
  @QuartzDataSource
  public DataSource dataSource() {
    return new HikariDataSource(hikariConfig());
  }
}
```

And here is my `DatasourceConfigurationTest.java` file:

```
import com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.TestPropertySource;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension;

import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:application.properties")
@ContextConfiguration(classes = DatasourceConfiguration.class)
class DatasourceConfigurationTest {

  @Autowired
  private ApplicationContext context;

  @Test
  void validateConfiguration() throws SQLException {
    assertThat(this.context.getBeansOfType(DataSource.class)).hasSize(1);
    HikariDataSource dataSource = this.context.getBean(HikariDataSource.class);
    assertThat(dataSource.getConnection().getMetaData().getURL()).isEqualTo("jdbc:h2:mem:simple");
    assertThat(dataSource.getMaximumPoolSize()).isEqualTo(42);
  }
}
```

When I run the Unit Test, I recognized that it failed to load ApplicationContext.
Here is the log:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
              at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:132)
              at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:124)
              at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:118)
              at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'getHikariConfig' defined in com.gm.gcc.vas.utility.messageretry.config.DatasourceConfiguration: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig]: Factory method 'getHikariConfig' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to load driver class test-driver-classname in either of HikariConfig class loader or Thread context classloader
              at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:658)
              at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:486)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig]: Factory method 'getHikariConfig' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to load driver class test-driver-classname in either of HikariConfig class loader or Thread context classloader
              at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
              at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653)
              ... 87 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to load driver class test-driver-classname in either of HikariConfig class loader or Thread context classloader
              at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig.setDriverClassName(HikariConfig.java:491)
              at com.gm.gcc.vas.utility.messageretry.config.DatasourceConfiguration.getHikariConfig(DatasourceConfiguration.java:37)
              ... 88 common frames omitted
```

Here is the properties file:

```
spring.datasource.scheduler.driverClassname=test-driver-classname
spring.datasource.scheduler.jdbcUrl=jdbc:test-url
spring.datasource.scheduler.password=test-password
spring.datasource.scheduler.username=test-username
```

As my understanding, when trying to create a connection, it failed because of dummy values.
I just wonder if my approach to do the unit test is correct or not, if yes, how can I fix the ApplicationContext error? Else, what is the correct way to ensure 100% converage.

Comment: do you happen to put the `application.properties` in the test resources folder as well?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute integration tests, you need a running DB instance to which Spring can connect. Your test is not a unit test as it is extended with the `SpringExtension`.

You could use an embedded H2 database for your tests, you would then need to add H2 as test dependency in your `pom.xml`:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

In your `application-test.properties`:

```
spring.datasource.scheduler.driverClassname=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.scheduler.jdbcUrl=jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
spring.datasource.scheduler.password=sa
spring.datasource.scheduler.username=sa
```

In order to have the `application-test.properties` loaded for your test you should either replace the `@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:application.properties")` with `@ActiveProfiles("test")` or reference the file `@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:application-test.properties")`.

Another good alternative would be using the [`Testcontainers`](https://www.testcontainers.org/) project which allows you to run the database that you use in production (like Postgres or MySQL) in a docker container. Here is [a good tutorial by Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/docker-test-containers).

Comment: We use this implementation but I want to note that H2 is not 1:1 with Oracle syntax. Just a note that some queries for Oracle when ran against this H2 instance may break giving false negatives in unit tests.